# Spring framework Web MVC is good but what framework are used to put widgets on Web page for simple entities CRUD?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, widget, jstl

I spend too many time on writing simple pages that allow *creating new/listing by filter/editing/deleting* entities. Each time I need to write a lot of superfluous code to make standard widget elements like drop-down select menu:

```
<select name="company" id="company_select" required="required">
  <c:if test="${isCompaniesWithPrompt}">
    <option value="x-non-existent">Select...</option>
  </c:if>
  <c:forEach var="i" items="${companies}">
    <option value="${i.id}" ${(not empty company && company.id == i.id) ? "selected=''" : ""}>${i.name}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

There are also a lot more common widgets that require a lot of superfluous work to get it in pure HTML5+JS+CSS and bridging it to Spring MVC like: prompt completion, tag selection, multi-check selection, etc.

Beside `JSP` I have to write `CSS` and supporting `JS` (validation code, or date-picker, color picker, etc).

I reduce some code by **JSP tag files** and **JSP tag lib** but that introduce custom nonstandard implementation.

I want to stop to invent bicycle. Are there any Spring integrated Web widget library for JSP?

**UPDATE** I just remembered *Django Admin* UI what allow viewing and editing entities without lines on code! I will be glad any like integration with Spring.

Answer (score 2):

If you like scaffolding (e.g. auto generation of CRUD pages for your model objects) then take a look at [Spring Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/) - it's not a widget library, but you can quickly build up a new application from scratch and then, optionally, remove Roo and continue with standard Spring MVC.

Comment: Thanks for interest to a question +1